# Simulate a monitor and get a video stream on windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, multiple-monitors

Is there a way for me to programatically set up a fake monitor in windows and get a video stream from it? Is there something in the win32 api that will allow me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it will be allowed by Microsoft to emulate a monitor, as it would then be easy to bypass copy-protection mechanisms in the system for videostreams.

Comment: Some of the answers to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752031/windows-is-it-possible-to-create-a-virtual-video-card-driver) might be useful/relevant.

Comment: [Mirror Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think Windows desktop objects are your answer. Here's an example of an application that uses them:

> Unlike other virtual desktop utilities that implement their desktops by showing the windows that are active on a desktop and hiding the rest, Sysinternals Desktops uses a Windows desktop object for each desktop. Application windows are bound to a desktop object when they are created, so Windows maintains the connection between windows and desktops and knows which ones to show when you switch a desktop. [...]
>
> Desktops reliance on Windows desktop objects means that it cannot provide some of the functionality of other virtual desktop utilities, however. For example, Windows doesn't provide a way to move a window from one desktop object to another, and because a separate Explorer process must run on each desktop to provide a taskbar and start menu, most tray applications are only visible on the first desktop. Further, there is no way to delete a desktop object, so Desktops does not provide a way to close a desktop, because that would result in orphaned windows and processes. The recommended way to exit Desktops is therefore to logoff.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to emulate **monitor**.

May be desktop functions match your criteria? Look to [CreateDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[SwitchDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Are you sure there's no way using custom driver or something like that? This software seems to be doing it http://www.maxivista.com/ . I want to be able to drag windows from my monitor to the fake one just like with multiple displays.

Comment: Driver is much more complicated task ) And it's related to DDK, not SDK. Why you want to do this "programmatically"? May be you can use VMWare, for example?